# full entity framework repository interface

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I am looking for full ef repository interface (and implementation). I have this:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T: class
{
    IQueryable<T> GetQuery();

    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    IEnumerable<T> Find(Func<T, bool> where);
    T Single(Func<T, bool> where);
    T First(Func<T, bool> where);

    void Delete(T entity);
    void Add(T entity);
    void Attach(T entity);
    void SaveChanges();
}
```

And I am looking an interface of all methods include SingleOrDefault and so on.
Where I can find such thing?

Comment: `SingleOrDefault()` is an extension method for `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @Bala R: I know, I am looking for complete interface and implementation of all IObjectSet so I can expose all the methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways to define repository. First is by exposing IQueryable which is enough to do anything:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T: class
{
    IQueryable<T> GetQuery();

    // This method requires additional knowledge about entity
    // or more compilcated approach. The point of the method
    // is to check EF's internal storage first before querying DB 
    // T GetById(int Id);        

    void Delete(T entity);
    void Add(T entity);
    void Attach(T entity);
}
```

Having anything like `GetAll` or `First` is simply redundant because `GetQuery` servers it all. The second approach is specific repository where you don't expose `IQueryable`:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();

    // Expressions!!!! Func will load all items to memeory
    // and then perform filtering by linq-to-objects!!!!!!
    IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
    T Single(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
    T First(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);

    void Delete(T entity);
    void Add(T entity);
    void Attach(T entity);
}
```

The second version is then derived by concrete repository interfaces which add methods like GetXXXOrderedByName, GetXXXWithRelatedYYY, etc.

Another point is that `SaveChanges` is usually not part of repository because you can need to modify items from multiple repositories and save changes on all of them by single method. For this purpose another pattern exists - unit of work.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of all methods on IEnumerable [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do install T4Scaffolding nuget package from nuget package manager.

Install this package to your model class library project or in a new project class library called repository

then in package manager console select  model class library project then type

scaffold repository [DomainClasses.Alias] -DbContextType:[ContextClass]

[image]

you get generated interface and implementation of repository class for your domain class

if you are using visual studio 2015 I suggest you to use nugetPackage 
T4Scaffolding.VS2015

[image]

if you want to generalize your repositories then you can just replace classes with T entity

for more details http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/using-t4scaffolding-to-create-dbcontext-and-repository-from-domain-classes/